# MVC jQuery Ajax Post - can only get it to work with hard-coded values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have a basic controller accepting a post..

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submit(string postCost)
    {
        //Do stuff here before sending back redirect details...

        return Json(new { result = "Redirect", url = Url.Action("Index", "Confirm") });
    }
```

And I'm posting via jquery ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: partyURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json', //charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { postCost: postageCost},   //**This fails!**
    //data: "{'postCost':'3.50'}",    //**This works**
    success: function (response) {

        if (response.result == 'SoldOut') {
            $("#soldOut").show();
        }
        else if (response.result == 'Redirect') {
            //All good, onward to confirmation page
            window.location = response.url;
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
       // Error handling here
    }
});
```

where the postageCost variable sent in when it fails returning status 500:

```
postageCost = '3.50';
postageCost = JSON.stringify(postageCost); //also fails with this
```

but if I hard-code the data definition as

```
data: "{'postCost':'3.50'}",
```

It works fine.

The key must therefore lie in what I'm doing with the data element?

Comment: Check the Network tab for the error that was returned. (and have you tried `data: JSON.stringify({ postCost: postageCost}),`

Comment: @StephenMuecke - data: JSON.stringify({ postCost: postageCost}) worked. If you post as an answer you can have the sweets. Thanks :)

Comment: Ozil has just posted an answer so you can accept that (although you don't need the quotes around `postCost`). And as a side note, why is your methods parameter not `(decimal postCost)`?

Comment: Your controller expects a string, not a json or an object. `Submit(string postCost)` Can't you change that so you work with json all along?

Comment: OK @StephenMuecke - I'd originally stated you could get the points as I was trying yours before ozils answer, but he can have it then. Why accepting as string? I think I had been round the houses so much I'd amended it to get it going. Changed thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do

```
var datum = {'postCost': '3.50'};
data: JSON.stringify(datum),   //Ajax call data
```

Comment: Thanks ozil :) I hadn't realised you could stringify in the data: segment.